# Can I Nope a Defuse?

Tags: exploding-kittens

If Alice draws an Exploding Kitten which she tries to Defuse, can Bob Nope that, making the kitten explode and eliminate Alice?

---

*At the time of asking, I had only played it once, an hour before. As it wasn't my own game, I had no access to the rule <s>book</s> leaflet.*

Comment: Not sure why this is +6.  It is pretty much the epitome of "This question doesn't show any research effort?"

Comment: @Kevin Well it's +6 for 1,962 views. I'm thinking that "exploding kittens" and "can I nope a defuse?" are attracting amused viewers from the hot questions list.

Comment: @Dronz maybe I'll post "How many dice do you roll in Monopoly?" and see how many views and upvotes I get.  As a test, or course. Not in any way to reap cheap reputation points

Comment: @Kevin Try that one and the same question about Cat-opoly and of Monopoly: Cat Lovers' Edition, and see how they each do.

Comment: @Kevin I saw [a question about keeping your hand secret](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/29324/6352) and now I feel a bit less bad about this question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Nope.

From [the rules](https://explodingkittens.com/downloads/rules/Exploding_Kittens_Party_Pack_Edition_Rules.pdf)

> **Nope**
>
> Stop any action except for an Exploding Kitten  **or a Defuse Card**.
> Imagine that any card (or  Pair  or  Special Combo ) beneath a Nope
> Card no longer exists

You can not nope a defuse card.

Comment: Huh. Must have missed that. Didn't feel right, though, so we didn't allow it.

Comment: You can always blame the kitten.

Comment: We house-ruled this in for fun. Definitely consider who you're playing with if you choose to do so.

Comment: So can you Nope your own draw?

Comment: @Acccumulation, the second part states "any card" so it does not counter a draw.